# Can an editor in Google Apps Script deploy a web app ?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone with edit rights (not owner) in Google Apps Script deploy a web app? I am the owner of a Google Web App and I would like a collaborator to also be able to deploy the script. As I cannot have two owners for the Web App the other person is an editor and as such, cannot deploy the web app. Any insights would be much appreciated.

*Note that I am not asking about local scripts or container bound scripts. Nor is this question about edit rights to a script - this question is about deployment rights only*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An editor can not deploy a webapp , only the owner can do the initial deployment.

But editors can manage versions and update the deployed version as well so it shouldn't be a major issue if you only have to do the initial deployment yourself and let your collaborator work and develop the app afterwards.
(This was announced in [release note march 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013#march_2013))

Comment: In addition, a non-domain editor can't access the /dev or /exec urls after a web app is deployed as only being visible to the owner's domain. This has been a small pain point when trying to support client apps after they initially deploy and use / have to have that setting.